# Marker now showing on google map using GM api in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am new to WordPress. but I know all the basics of PHP.
I am trying to show google map into my website using google map API. I have read the tutorials and did exactly the same but marker is not showing on WordPress.

What I have done already :
I have created the template by the name of template-maps

here is my code :

```
function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
      zoom: 13
    });
    var input = /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(
        document.getElementById('pac-input'));

    var types = document.getElementById('type-selector');
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(types);

    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
    autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29)
    });

    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
      infowindow.close();
      marker.setVisible(false);
      var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
      if (!place.geometry) {
        window.alert("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");
        return;
      }

      // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
      } else {
        map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
        map.setZoom(17);  // Why 17? Because it looks good.
      }
      marker.setIcon(/** @type {google.maps.Icon} */({
        url: place.icon,
        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 35)
      }));
      marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
      marker.setVisible(true);

      var address = '';
      if (place.address_components) {
        address = [
          (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
          (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
          (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
        ].join(' ');
      }

      infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' + address);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });

    // Sets a listener on a radio button to change the filter type on Places
    // Autocomplete.
    function setupClickListener(id, types) {
      var radioButton = document.getElementById(id);
      radioButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        autocomplete.setTypes(types);
      });
    }

    setupClickListener('changetype-all', []);
    setupClickListener('changetype-address', ['address']);
    setupClickListener('changetype-establishment', ['establishment']);
    setupClickListener('changetype-geocode', ['geocode']);
  }
```

HTML code: 
    
    
      
      All

```
  <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-establishment">
  <label for="changetype-establishment">Establishments</label>

  <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-address">
  <label for="changetype-address">Addresses</label>

  <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-geocode">
  <label for="changetype-geocode">Geocodes</label>
</div>
<div id="map-canvas"></div><!-- #map-canvas -->
```

Comment: show the html code related to the map ..

Comment: @scaisEdge I have edit the question. please see now. I am using google places API now

Comment: you have a css related to map-canvas ?

Comment: #map-canvas {
 
 width:    100%;
 height:   500px;
 
}

Comment: is the page where there is the map .. visibile or is hidden and you access by a tab ?

Comment: yes, this code is all on one page, and i am using custom template, and accessing it by tab, i just use view page from WordPress admin apnel

Comment: If you use a tab under the tab select you should add a javascript call od the init map..  otherwise the map is not properly rendered by google

Comment: I know, it's not appropriate according to rules of stack overflow but is it possible that u come on team viewer and see my code, and then I will update the solution here ??

Comment: No  teamviewer  no .. but you can update the question  and show the code of how you set the tab .. and i can take a look

Comment: Ok, as i told you i didn't set this page in any tab, and i just created a new page by custom template and access it through the web address

Comment: In have posted an answer seem wrong id

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong id

Here you are creating a map for id = map

```
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
```

but you have div and css  id for map equal to

```
   <div id="map-canvas">

   #map-canvas { width: 100%; height: 500px; }
```

then you should use

```
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
```